ORA-01031 : Cross Schema Procedure Execution Issue
I have three schemas META, DATA and a Custom schema in an Oracle DB.
I've declared one simple procedure in META schema.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1 ( v_name IN VARCHAR2 ) IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello, ' || v_name);
END TEST1;
/

I haven't given any grants on DATA or CUSTOM schema for this procedure.
When i try to run this procedure in DATA schema as META.TEST1 it works.
But when I try the same in CUSTOM schema i'm getting "insufficient privileges"
The procedure is using Definer's Rights.
I can also see that EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE is granted as a system privilege to both the DATA and CUSTOM schema.
Both the DATA and CUSTOM schema has same session privileges and same roles privileges assigned to them. They also have many synonyms from the META schema.
I want to know why its working for DATA but not for CUSTOM schema.
I've tried my best to find the difference between any privileges but I'm unable to find one.
All the queries results in them being almost similar in nature with regards to privileges.

Are there any objects in the CUSTOM schema that are named META? Maybe a synonym? (I can't actually think of a scenario that would give that error, but it appears it's referring to the wrong thing somehow; possibly including your actual call and the full error stack you get back might reveal something...)

other things worth checking are:  1) are you calling this procedure not using sysnonms; (begin meta.test() end;) from each non-owner schema and 2) does the working user have DBA or EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE system privileges?

Check user privileges in dba_sys_privs for DATA and custom schema and compare if there is a missing privilege for Custom schema

They are exactly the same.
I've checked sys_privs, session_privs and sys_roles.

grant execute on META.TEST1 to CUSTOM schema.  This should work
